# System.Web.Routing in .net 3.5 (Not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I've used routing with asp.net 4.0 but one of my hosting companies haven't updated .net framework yet and I want to use routing with asp.net 3.5. Is it possible to use System.Web.Routing in asp.net 3.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use System.Web.Routing with ASP.NET 3.5 provided you have SP1.  See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) on how to use it with web forms.

Comment: Thanks but is there an easier way like asp.net 4?

Comment: what do you mean easier?  It's very easy.

Comment: Maybe it is but I couldn't get it work... Also there is too much code. I just want in in asp.net 4.0 way :).. Which is just importing System.Web.Routing and register route table in global.asax.